# How to save multiple gridview row data to database in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I have a gridview control in my project in which i wanted to save multiple gridview rows back to the database. How do i get save all rows through looping. Please help me to overcome this problem.

[image]

```
//Save TestDetails

   foreach (GridViewRow rw in GridView1.Rows)
    {
            var n = new TestDetail
            {
                ServiceId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[rw.RowIndex].Value),
                Service = rw.Cells[1].Text.ToString(),  //getting input error
                Price = Convert.ToInt32(rw.Cells[2].Text.ToString())  //getting input error
            };

            using (var context = new DiagEntities())
            {
                context.TestDetail.Add(n);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
     }
```

Comment: please show the gridview markup

Answer (score 1):

If you are in edit mode, you could check the control collection of the particular cell... it should context the textbox containing the value.

```
Service = ((TextBox)(rw.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text.ToString(),
Price = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)(rw.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text.ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks "Scartag" for your reply... there is no textbox control associated inside the gridview control.

Comment: @Apurba Yeah they won't be till you have an edit mode .. do you get into edit mode before the saving occurs? how do the values change that requires saving?